# Postgres Stored Procedure in Datastage

Tags: postgresql, datastage

I am using Data Stage version 11.5. We recently migrated from Oracle to PostgreSQL. But now I am facing issues in how to call the PostgreSQL procedure in Datastage.

Comment: To call a stored procedure (not **function**!)  you use the [call](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-call.html) command

Comment: You should really tell what kind of issues you're facing. Or if your questions is how to call a procedure, you should ask that.

Answer (score 0):

CALL executes a procedure.

If the procedure has any output parameters, then a result row will be returned, containing the values of those parameters.

See: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-call.html